# Aplicacion lenta desde que puse multiDex en Android

Tags: android, google-maps, gradle

mi aplicacion se demora bastante en iniciar desde que coloque `multiDexEnabled true` en el `gradle module` así como tambien `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'` antes no demoraba tanto en que mi aplicacion se iniciaba y como utilizo el activity de mapas necesito usar esto. Alguien que me diga que puedo hacer en estos casos.

> gradle actual

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "desarrolladoresalpha.hassmovilcortes"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile files('libs/GenAsync.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes adjuntar el gradle que tienes actualmente?

Comment: Listo lo he adjuntado

Comment: porque no cargas solo los play-services de mapas y no todo entero

Answer (score 2):

Si solo usas los play services de mapas, no debes cargar todo el pack entero

En la siguiente enlace puedes obtener por separado cada servicio [split-play-services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split)

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'`

y a continuación puedes precindir del `multi-dex`

Comment: entonces con solo poner el **'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'** ya?

Comment: Si solo usas los mapas si, en el enlace que te he pasado hay todos los servicios desglosados, por ejemplo si usas autentificación de google pues cargas tambien su pack, si usas android wear, cargas lo que necesitas.

Comment: @ManuelMorales tienes que especificar con maps
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services **-maps** :10.0.1'